# how to format multiple strings into array format

Tags: java, arrays, string, format

i have this long list of zipcodes here

```
90019,90036,90016,90005,90010,90018,90020,90004,90048,90035,90211,90006,90038,90008,90089,90062,90007,90028,90034,90212,90232,90231,90233,90057,90209,90213,90070,90029,90069,90015,90056,90037,90017,90067,90043,90046,90026,90071,90014,90230,90064,90099,90302,90189,90011,90030,90050,90051,90052,90053,90054,90055,90060,90072,90074,90075,90076,90078,90080,90081,90082,90083,90086,90087,90088,90093,90024,90009,90013,90068,90090,90079,90012,90210,90021,90025,90306,90307,90308,90309,90310,90312,90311,90095,90305,91608,90027,90084,90066,90301,90073,90094,90047,91522,91604,90039,90003,90044,91602,90031,91204,91523,90033,90295,90001,90045,90077,91521,90065,90096,90404,90292,90405,90303,90058,90294,90304,90291,91209,91221,91222,91224,91225,91226,91210,91205,90023,91203,91601,91393,91506,91423,90063,90002,90403,90255,91607,91603,91609,91610,91611,91612,91614,91615,91616,91617,91618,90406,90407,90408,90409,90410,90411,90049,91201,91505,91502,90401,90251,90296,90293,91503,91507,91508,91510,91526,90402,91202,90250,91413,90032,90042,90061,90270,90041,91495,90245,91403,91606,90059,90249,91401,91501,91207,91206,91504,90261,90022,90247,91754,90201,90222,90091,90260,91208,91411,91803,90040,91030,91404,91407,91408,91409,91410,91470,91482,91496,91499,90506,90280,91605,90267,90266,90262,91436,91353,91031,91105,90248,91416,91426,91801,90272,91804,90504,90278,90202,91405,91123,91756,90223,90224,91802,91896,91899,91046,91714,91715,91352,91103,91716,91021,91316,91020,91755,90254,91102,91109,91110,91114,91115,91116,91117,91118,91121,91124,91125,91126,91129,91182,91184,91185,91188,91189,90220,91101,91406,91106,90640,91012,90747,91412,91214,91108,90746,91778,91402,91356,90239,90221,90240,91776,90723,90242,91043,90241,90503,90661,90662,90507,90508,90509,90510,91770,91775,91357,91104,90502,91331,91199,90660,90501,91334,91041,90277,91343,90749,91337,91003,91771,91772,91001,91385,91335,91333,90290,90805,90895,90745,91346,91395,90671,91107,91325,90706,90610,91040,90606,91733,91364,91371,91327,91328,91329,91345,90505,91780,91731,90264,91042,91341,91330,90707,90810,91365,91340,91007,91396,90710,91306,90807,90717,90712,90711,90714,90651,90652,91734,91735,91324,90650,91367,91305,91308,91309,91303,90601,91025,91394,90607,90608,90609,90670,91006,91066,91077,90602,91372,91024,91011,91732,90806,91392,90713,90748,90274,90744,91302,90702,90701,91344,90755,91746,90605,91023,90703
```

and i want to be able to format them into a string array

```
String[] zipcodes = {};
```

like this

```
String[] zipcodes = {"90019", "90022", "90006"};
```

is there a quick way to do this without manually putting quote marks and commas?

Comment: `String.split(",");`

Comment: You said a List of zipcode.  Is it a List or a long String?

Comment: `String[] zipCodes = string.split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.split(",")`

```
String str = "90019,90036,90016,90005,90010,90018,90020,90004,90048,90035,90211,90006,90038,90008,90089,90062,90007,90028,90034,90212,90232,90231,90233,90057,90209,90213,90070,90029,90069,90015,90056,90037,90017,90067,90043,90046,90026,90071,90014,90230,90064,90099,90302,90189,90011,90030,90050,90051,90052,90053,90054,90055,90060,90072,90074,90075,90076,90078,90080,90081,90082,90083,90086,90087,90088,90093,90024,90009,90013,90068,90090,90079,90012,90210,90021,90025,90306,90307,90308,90309,90310,90312,90311,90095,90305,91608,90027,90084,90066,90301,90073,90094,90047,91522,91604,90039,90003,90044,91602,90031,91204,91523,90033,90295,90001,90045,90077,91521,90065,90096,90404,90292,90405,90303,90058,90294,90304,90291,91209,91221,91222,91224,91225,91226,91210,91205,90023,91203,91601,91393,91506,91423,90063,90002,90403,90255,91607,91603,91609,91610,91611,91612,91614,91615,91616,91617,91618,90406,90407,90408,90409,90410,90411,90049,91201,91505,91502,90401,90251,90296,90293,91503,91507,91508,91510,91526,90402,91202,90250,91413,90032,90042,90061,90270,90041,91495,90245,91403,91606,90059,90249,91401,91501,91207,91206,91504,90261,90022,90247,91754,90201,90222,90091,90260,91208,91411,91803,90040,91030,91404,91407,91408,91409,91410,91470,91482,91496,91499,90506,90280,91605,90267,90266,90262,91436,91353,91031,91105,90248,91416,91426,91801,90272,91804,90504,90278,90202,91405,91123,91756,90223,90224,91802,91896,91899,91046,91714,91715,91352,91103,91716,91021,91316,91020,91755,90254,91102,91109,91110,91114,91115,91116,91117,91118,91121,91124,91125,91126,91129,91182,91184,91185,91188,91189,90220,91101,91406,91106,90640,91012,90747,91412,91214,91108,90746,91778,91402,91356,90239,90221,90240,91776,90723,90242,91043,90241,90503,90661,90662,90507,90508,90509,90510,91770,91775,91357,91104,90502,91331,91199,90660,90501,91334,91041,90277,91343,90749,91337,91003,91771,91772,91001,91385,91335,91333,90290,90805,90895,90745,91346,91395,90671,91107,91325,90706,90610,91040,90606,91733,91364,91371,91327,91328,91329,91345,90505,91780,91731,90264,91042,91341,91330,90707,90810,91365,91340,91007,91396,90710,91306,90807,90717,90712,90711,90714,90651,90652,91734,91735,91324,90650,91367,91305,91308,91309,91303,90601,91025,91394,90607,90608,90609,90670,91006,91066,91077,90602,91372,91024,91011,91732,90806,91392,90713,90748,90274,90744,91302,90702,90701,91344,90755,91746,90605,91023,90703";
String[] zipcodes = str.split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the split() method for Strings

```
String[] zipcodes = theString.trim().split(",");
```